# Inherited class that changes all inherited public methods to private

Tags: java, android, class, inheritance, private

I want to make my own UI widget class for android that is inherited class of LinearLayout.

```
public class MyOwnClass extends LinearLayout {

    ...
    public void setSomeProperties(Object properties) { ... }
```

But LinearLayout has a lot of public methods and I want the only public methods that I define in my class. How to make all those public methods of LinearLayout inaccessible for instances of MyOwnClass?

```
myOwnClass.setSomeProperties(properties); // only this should be accesible
myOwnClass.setBackground(...); // this should'nt be accesible
```

Comment: but thats increbidle amount of methods.. i dont want to have all of them in my class

Comment: "But LinearLayout has a lot of public methods and I want the only public methods that I define in my class" -- you will have no choice but to have "a lot of public methods", as those are defined on `View` as being public, and you will need to inherit from `View` to create your own "UI widget class". For example, [`setBackground()` is defined on `View` as being `public`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)), and so you will not be able to make that be anything other than `public`.

Comment: That's pretty frustrating

Answer (score 5):

You should use composition instead of inheritance.

You can do it by wrapping an isntance of `LinearLayout` within your `MyOwnClass` instead of inheriting from it. Then you can choose which methods are public.

```
public class MyOwnClass {
    LinearLayout layout;

    public MyOwnClass ()
    {
        layout = new LinearLayout ();
    }

    // do the following only for methods of LinearLayout you wish to stay public in
    // new class 
    public SomeReturnValue someMethod (... someParams ...)
    {
        return layout.someMethod (... someParams ...)
    }
}
```

This way you have full control over which public methods of the `LinearLayout` contained within your new class are still accessible to users of your new class.

Comment: what does wrapping mean exactly? Do i have just to create an instance of LinearLayout in my class and store it as a field of my class?

Comment: @Incredible Yes, that's what it means, as shown in my code sample.

Comment: @Eran: In general, your answer is correct, hence my upvote. In the specific case of the question, most of the `public` methods are really defined on a base class (`View`) that the OP's class will also need to extend to be the OP's own "UI widget class". Hence, in practice, in this situation, this will result in a lot of code and very little additional visibility control.

Comment: But how can be the LinearLayout inflated in activity for exmaple, when another programmer uses my class? If MyOwnClass is LinearLayout itself it is easy to inflate that view, but what if LinearLayout is wrapped in new class?